# Logstash 7 not Adding Date Stamp to Index Name

Tags: logstash, logstash-configuration

I just updated from ELK 6.7.0 to 7.4.0 (via 6.8.0).  After I started my 7.4.0 instance, logstash started putting the data into an index called "logstash" instead of "logstash-2019.10.24" like it used to.

I updated my output plugin to look like

```
output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["localhost"]
    index => "logstash-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
  }
}
```

I didn't used to have the "index" part, but I tried that to see if it would help, restarted logstash, and it's still putting data into the "logstash" index.

How can I get logstash to use the date-stamped indexes again?

(I am running just a single-node in docker: https://github.com/kenwdelong/elk-docker/tree/ELK-7.4.0)

Strangely, if I spin up the same tagged docker image on a clean machine, and shove some data into it using the test script on my github page, it works fine and I get the date in the index name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured this out. I had an installed template called "logstash" with the index pattern "logstash-*".  This template was from a long time ago and still had the "*defaults*" key directly underneath "mappings".  Apparently this prevented ES 7 from creating the index, so Logstash somehow fell back to the "logstash" index.  I had to drop the logstash template, then recreate it without the "*defaults*" key.  Also, I ran into some problems where records were not being indexed because of ECS - ES was assuming that certain fields (like userAgent) were one type when actually everything I have was set up to be different type.  So I had to iron out those problems too.